# Using strings as events is deprecated and will be removed in a future version

Tags: angular, grafana

I am using the following command to generate my new Grafana project:

```
npx @grafana/toolkit plugin:create my-plugin
```

After deploying and browsing to the dashboard i see in the console:

> Using strings as events is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. (init-edit-mode)
>   Using strings as events is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. (render) 
>   Using strings as events is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. (data-error)

The code in the template looks like this:

```
this.events.on('init-edit-mode', this.onInitEditMode.bind(this));
this.events.on('render', this.onRender.bind(this));
this.events.on('data-error', this.onDataError.bind(this));

this.events.on(PanelEvents.dataReceived, this.onDataReceived.bind(this));
this.events.on(PanelEvents.dataSnapshotLoad, this.onDataReceived.bind(this));
this.events.on(PanelEvents.editModeInitialized, this.onInitEditMode.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't now why they did not fix that in the template but here is the solution.

Luckily they have constants in their `PanelEvents` namespace.

So you can simply do:

```
this.events.on(PanelEvents.editModeInitialized, this.onInitEditMode.bind(this));
this.events.on(PanelEvents.render, this.onRender.bind(this));
this.events.on(PanelEvents.dataError, this.onDataError.bind(this));
```

This makes the console in the browser happy.